# How to clone, based on a subpath within a remote repository

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm new to git. I would like to clone a public remote git repository. I can successfully access this URL in my browser, and although the URL is https, no authentication is required. But when I attempt to clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/6.0.x/drools-examples-api/named-kiesession-from-file
```

I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'named-kiesession-from-file'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/6.0.x/drools-examples-api/named-kiesession-from-file/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I think the problem is that I may not have the root of the repository here, but rather a subpath. How do I determine what path is actually the root of the repository? Or is there a way to clone just a subpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't clone just a folder of a repository. You need to clone the whole repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:droolsjbpm/drools.git
```

Comment: Is there a way, given an arbitrary URL, to determine what the repository root is?

Comment: Its the part of the url which ends with `*.git`

Comment: What about when there is no `.git` in the URL (as in my case)? The URL is `https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/6.0.x/drools-examples-api/named-kiesession-from-file`

Comment: Oh, I see. Then (on github) it is: `github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME + .git` - meaning the first two components of the path + `.git`